# Add an external library as a dependency in module.xml

Tags: java, jboss

I have different packages in my project. In one of these I have a folder containing a particular library (zip file).

Another jar (let's call it `JAR_A`) depends on this library.
Until now in the `module.xml` of this `JAR_A`, I have added some dependencies, which were structured as module themselves in JBoss structure (or else they are located in a folder main with the respective file `module.xml`).

Thanks to the `name` attribute contained in `module.xml`, I was able to add the dependency in the `module.xml` of my `JAR_A`.

Now, as the external library (zip file) is not a module and doesn't have it's `module.xml` file with a name specified....how can I refer to it in order to add it's dependency in `JAR_A` ?

Comment: were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

For one module to depend on another module you can use the dependencies XML block like in Maven.

```
<dependencies>
        <module name="moduleNameOfModuleWithJAR_A"/>
</dependencies>
```